# This query is working but I want to know if I can have it shortened

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to extract the last word from a string field... If it is a name of month, I want to convert it to month in Number. It is working but it's too long. Can we contain " Incorrect datetime value" or on date format error then display blank?

If then else not working well...

```
case 
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "January" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "February" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1))= "March" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "April" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "May" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "June" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "July" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "August" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "September" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "October" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "November" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "December" then (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
else null
end  as `Last_NuM_Month`
```

This sample is working but too long.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can reduce your code to just the line below:

```
SELECT (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M'))) AS `Last_NuM_Month`;
```

MySQL's [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) will return `NULL` if you have an invalid month name like "februember" in your `tbl_StringsList.items`

Comment: This will returrn and error " Incorrect datetime value" for those records that does not end with a month name.

What you suggested is my orginal code... But the issue is that some strings in the feild does not content month name string... meaning I need to take only the month name in the last word of the string and make a null value if last word is not a month name... 

I appreciate your reply.

Comment: Sorry I cannot post the complete query.

Comment: I see... It's a bit difficult without having all the context. But  you could consider putting that logic inside a sql function. Other improvement, to make it horizontally shorter, is to return the month number directly, like: `when (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) = "January" then 1`. As we know that "Jauary" is a valid month (and is always the first), we don't need to calculate its number.

Comment: Thanks so much CaConde, I appreciate your ideas, it make a lot of sense actually, I can simplify further the "then"... 
Why use:
(MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M'))), when I can actually just put the 1 thru 12... Great idea and I am sure will lessen the query time also.

Answer (score 0):

You could change to this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)) IN 
    (
        'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
        'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
    )
    THEN (MONTH(str_to_date((SUBSTRING_INDEX(tbl_StringsList.items, " ", -1)),'%M')))
    ELSE NULL
END AS `Last_NuM_Month`
```

Tested in [rextester](https://rextester.com/YHYG44021)

Comment: Thanks.

This looks good but when I merge this to my complete select / insert query it returns error: 

"[Err] 1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size"

I appreciate your reply, it's good to remember the "IN" cant be used as list in my conditions.

Comment: I will experiment this with the suggestion and Cacode's, code will be so much shorter and will find out which can execute faster.... Thanks! By the way I handled the error "[Err] 1206 - The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size" by expanding innodb_buffer_pool_size.